# How can you create a PushTopic with SOAP/REST API in Node (jsforce)

Tags: javascript, node.js, salesforce

According to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48901/create-streaming-pushtopic-using-rest-api I should be able to use the standard sobject API to create a `PushTopic`. However when I do so I get an error of

> The requested resource does not exist.

In fact, I can't even describe the object.

I am using `node` and `jsforce` to test this. I have successfully used the `execute anonymous apex code` from the `developer console` to create a topic, but I require it to be done inside of my own server.

My code looks like:

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var config = {...};
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  oauth2 : {
    clientId : config.oauthClientId,
    clientSecret : config.oauthSecret,
    redirectUri : config.oauthCallbackUrl
  },
  instanceUrl : config.instanceUrl,
  accessToken : config.accessToken,
  refreshToken: config.refreshToken
});

conn
  .sobject('PushTopic')
  .describe()
  .then(function(ret){
    console.log('Description:', ret)
  }, function(err){
    console.log('Error:', err)
  });
```

I Get:

> Error { [NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist] name: 'NOT_FOUND', errorCode: 'NOT_FOUND' }

If I use `'Account'` instead of `'PushTopic'` I get:

> Description { actionOverrides: [],
>         activateable: false,
>         childRelationships:
>         ...

Is this a problem with `jsforce`? Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Ok. The problem was that my user did not have permissions for the PushTopic object. Even though I can subscribe to the streaming channel that the topic's produce (streaming api enabled), you need additional permissions to create a topic.

> Setup -> Manage Users -> Permission Sets -> New -> Save -> Object Settings -> Push Topics -> Edit

Then

> Manage Assignments -> Add Assignments

I created a permission set called 'PushTopic_Creator' and only added that permission, and then applied it to my user. I can now describe and create PushTopics!

Answer (score -1):

According to this document supported calls for REST are:

> REST: DELETE, GET, PATCH, POST (query requests are specified in the
>   URI)

Together with this, if you check samples in [Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/quick_start_workbench.htm) Streaming API config does not require Salesforce `describe()` call.

Comment: Thanks; I agree that it supports those calls - or should - which is why I'm confused about my result. Have you been able to create a topic with the API?